# integrate the following expression again

Tags: integration

Question:
$x - x^2 + 1$

My answer:
$\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} + {x} + C$

Correct answer:
$\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^2}{3} - \frac{x^3}{3} + x + C$

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Nothing.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: ok then what is the formula with which you get the "correct answer"? thank's

Comment: You use $\int x^{n}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$

Comment: I know but how do you derive the longer answer?

Comment: You don't - the longer answer is wrong!

Comment: Refer to the answer by DonAntonio.  He sums up what I said in more detail.  You shouldn't have a problem after that.

Comment: There are **no** two $\;-\frac{x^2}{3}\;$ in that indefinite integral!

Comment: hmm interesting because that is the answer given by teacher. maybe I asked her tomorrow. It is most likely then my miss writing. Thank you both!

Comment: Not that interesting @CashVai: either she made a honest mistake as we all do from time to time, or else she doesn't know. Hopefully it is the first possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula is

$$-1\neq n\in\Bbb Z \implies \int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

Instead of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ we can in fact take $\;-1\neq n\in\Bbb R\;$ .

and , of course, using linearity of integral:

$$\int (f(x)+g(x))dx=\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$$

and the above can be extended to any (finite) number of summands.